# SSRS Data label on first and last entry

Tags: reporting-services, linegraph, datapoint

I have a line graph which tracks days passed on the X-axis.

I would like for the data points to be visible on only the first entry and the last entry.

I tried the below, which I thought should show only the final entry, but in fact had the opposite effect.

```
=iif(Last(Fields!DateTime.Value),False, True)
```

Changing from the Last to the First (or Max or Min) all have the same effect.

An example with data point on only the first entry:
[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to show it explicitly where to look, so

=iif(Fields!DateTime.Value = Max(Fields!DateTime.Value, "BatchData") OR Fields!DateTime.Value = Min(Fields!DateTime.Value, "BatchData"),True,False)

Comment: on what property you did this.  Right Click on what, line?

Comment: This was a while ago but it would have been on the data label itself I think. Data label visibility.